# Time needed to empty a syringe

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics

A) a syringe is filled with 10mL water.
The diameter of the barrel of the syringe is 15.9 mm and the diameter of the tip is 1.2mm. With how much force do we need to push on the plunger to empty the syringe from water in 10 seconds? Neglect friction of the plunger and the waters viscosity.

B)Now we add a needle to the syringe, with a length of 25mm and diameter 0.210 mm. If you push on the plunger with a force 0.10 N, how much time will it take to empty the syringe? Now we should consider the viscosity of water: 0.0010Pas

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**For the first case:**

> Neglect friction of the plunger and the waters viscosity.

This means the only force needed is that to overcome inertia, acc. $\text{N2L}$ $(^*)$. This force is usually very small and most often neglected in similar problems.

**For the second case** we also ignore the minute inertial forces and you rightly suggest to use the [Hagen-Poiseuille equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hagen%E2%80%93Poiseuille_equation#Liquid_flow_through_a_pipe) for flow through pipes:

$$\Delta p=\frac{8 \mu LQ}{\pi R^4}\tag{1}$$

(for list and meaning of symbols, see link above)

The first thing to determine is $\Delta p$. The stated force of $0.1\mathrm{N}$ applied to the plunger and the plunger diameter allow to calculate the pressure in the barrel of the syringe:

$$p_1=\frac{F}{A}$$

where $F$ is the force and $A$ the cross-section of the plunger.

Now we make a very reasonable assumption, i.e. that the pressure loss due to flow through the barrel is very low compared to the pressure loss through the actual needle.

Because the pressure at the end tip of the needle is equal to atmospheric pressure $p_{atm}$, we can then write:

$$\Delta p \approx p_1-p_{atm}$$

We now have everything to apply $(1)$.

---

**Laminar or turbulent flow?**

An implicit assumption was made above, i.e. that the flow through the needle is laminar. This occurs for low [Reynolds number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reynolds_number#Definition):

$$\text{Re}=\frac{\rho v D}{\mu}$$

Because both $v$ and $D$ are small here, $\text{Re}$ will be small, indicating laminar flow.

Strictly speaking the laminarity assumption needs to be checked though. Should flow prove to be turbulent, then the [Darcy-Weisbach equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darcy%E2%80%93Weisbach_equation#In_terms_of_volumetric_flow) will have to be used to establish the flow/pressure relationship.

---

$(^*)$ It's also a little mathematically involved.

Let $F$ be a constant force applied to the plunger, which has cross-section $A$. The water's density is $\rho$, instantaneous mass of water held by the barrel is $m(t)$ and $v(t)$ is the instantaneous velocity of the plunger.

Apply $N2L$:

$$F=m(t)\frac{\text{d}v(t)}{\text{d}t}=m(t)v'(t)$$
During an infinitesimal time interval:
$$\text{d}m(t)=-A\rho v(t)\text{d}t$$
Derive w.r.t. $t$ the first equation, using the product rule:

$$\frac{\text{d}m(t)}{\text{d}t}v'(t)+m(t)v''(t)=0$$
Substitutions:
$$-A\rho vv'+\frac{F}{v'}v''=0$$
$$-A\rho v'^2v+Fv''=0$$
$$v''-\frac{A\rho}{F}vv'^2=0$$
which is a second order, non-linear ODE.

Comment: Could you please explain the idea of why the pressure loss through the barrel is very low compared to the needle?

Comment: Just look at the HP formula: if $R$ is small then $\Delta p$ is high. And $R$ appears at the FOURTH power! In general, all other things being equal, narrow pipes require more pressure than wider ones, for the same throughput.